# Stop event listeners on '$destroy'. TypeError: $on is not a function;

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, angularjs-events

I'm trying to stop all event listeners while scope is destroyed.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: vm.$on is not a function;
```

Neither vm.on(..) works

```
    angular.module('app.layout')
      .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

      DashboardController.$inject = ['$interval','dataservice'];


      function DashboardController($interval, dataservice) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = "DashboardController";


        console.log('Init Dashboard Controller');
        initEvents();
/*
 ...
*/

    /////////////////////////////

    function initEvents() {
          vm.$on('$destroy', function() {
            vm.stop();
            console.log('DashboardController scope destroyed.');
          })
        }
```

Comment: `vm` is a controller, not a scope.  This is a case where you would need to inject the `$scope` service.

Comment: I'm not AngularJS guy but $on is $scope method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vm` doesn't have the `$on(...` declared, you must use `$scope` instead. Inject it on your controller and declare like `$scope.$on`.

When using `controllerAs` syntax, this very often missunderstood that you shouldn't use `$scope` at all. However, the recomendation is to avoid using `$scope` for certain activities not abolish it from your controller. Scope always will exists, it's an internal of your controller, just don't use it like a view model, but you can use it anyways for such tasks like, listen to events, broadcast, emmit, etc.

Try something like (after you've injected `$scope` on your dependencies):

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    vm.stop();
    console.log('DashboardController scope destroyed.');
})
```